# picturebox1.Image = bmp VS picturebox1.Image = new Bitmap(bmp)?

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox

I use the common way to draw on a picturebox, that is drawing on a bitmap first and after copying it's content to the picturebox image.

```
Bitmap bmp;
bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Draw(...);
```

I was wondering that after dowing all the drawing staff is there any difference between using the followings?

```
pb.Image = bmp;
```

or

```
pb.Image = new Bitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: The 2nd syntax is a bug.  A pointless waste of memory *and* increases the odds to forget to call Dispose() correctly.  Forgetting to dispose the old bitmap assigned to Image is another classic bug.

Comment: It's not a bug, it actually creates a new clean copy of the bitmap.  Granted he should dispose the original, but this is not a bad way to go.  For speed I'd highly suggest clone.  Properly however I'd check if the picturebox image is null, if not dispose of it as well, in my experience they really suck at memory management.

Comment: Oh side note put a using on the graphics object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is pb.Image = bmp; Assigns the existing bitmap to your property. pb.Image = new Bitmap(bmp); Creates a new bitmap, it's essentially a deep copy.

Comment: You are right. Just the same behaviour as with any other class in .NET. I was confused because the picturebox needs a refresh to see the changes. And when doing the assignment the refresh is made automtically - that is why it looks like making a deep copy instead of just setting the reference.